# Convert string expression to mathematical expression?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm looking for something that would take a mathematical expression string as an input and would change it by adding parentheses to it.

For examples :

Input 1 : `"2*4^7"`

Output 1 : `"(2*(4^7))"`

Input 2 : `"sin(x)*3-8^9"`

Output 2 : `"((sin(x)*3)-(8^9))"`

Input 3 : `"(2-8)/6"`

Output 3 : `"((2-8)/6)"`

I'm currently trying to code it, but it's taking too much time and I would rather focus on other things, so if you guys know some module that could do that, that would be great.

I'm working with python 3

Thank you!

Comment: Try the `ast` module.

Comment: +1 for `ast`. Abstract syntax tree, I assume? 

Basically, you have to define a "language" (or "grammar") for what a mathematical expression, and then you can get a package to give you a parser that will turn an expression into a tree, the various elements of the formula are the nodes.

Comment: @Lagerbaer No need to define the language, Python is defined already. They can just do `ast.parse` on the string, and traverse the resulting tree.

Comment: oh yeah of course. Was thinking too complicated.

Comment: @L3viathan: The `ast` module is for Python syntax, and this syntax isn't Python. For one obvious incompatibility, `^` means something different, and it has a different precedence. It'd be better to get a real parser generator instead of using the Python parser.

Comment: @user2357112 Good point

Comment: is sympy not an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `ast` module, you can parse your string and then traverse it to build a string representation you require:

```
import ast

def represent(tree):
    t = type(tree)
    if t == ast.Module:
        return represent(tree.body)
    elif t == list:
        # arithmetic expression should only be one thing
        return ", ".join(represent(part) for part in tree)
    elif t == ast.Expr:
        return represent(tree.value)
    elif t == ast.BinOp:
        o = type(tree.op)
        if o == ast.BitXor:
            op = "^"
        elif o == ast.Mult:
            op = "*"
        elif o == ast.Add:
            op = "+"
        ...
        return "({}{}{})".format(
                represent(tree.left),
                op,
                represent(tree.right),
                )
    elif t == ast.Num:
        return str(tree.n)
    elif t == ast.Name:
        return tree.id
    elif t == ast.Call:
        return "{}({})".format(
                represent(tree.func),
                represent(tree.args),
                )
    ...

# prints (((sin(x)*2)*x)+4)
print(represent(ast.parse("sin(x)*2*x+4")))
```

As @user2357112 noted in the comments, this will only work if you limit yourself to use Python's expression syntax, most importantly by using `**` instead of `^` for exponentiation.

Comment: Wow, I'm realy impress by that. I almost finish coding it myself without any module but I found your solution way more useful. However, How can I implement a custom expression. For example, I would like to implement a vector synax like this : [x y z] and a matrix syntax like this {a b c; d e f; g h i}. So k*[x y z] + [a b c] would looks like ((k*[x y z]) + [a b c])

Comment: Yeah, that's why I added the line about caveats at the end: You won't be able to do that with this solution (except for hacky ways, like converting the string before you parse it). In this case my solution won't help you. Take a look at [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing)

Comment: Ok, will check on that. And thank for your help! @L3viathan.

Also I will just change [x y z] to vector(x,y,z) which work fine with your code.

Answer (score 0):

simply use `eval(expression)`

Replace character in `a = '2*4^7'` by `b=a.replace('^','**')` and so on
`eval(b)`

some variable can be used

ex:

```
x= 3
eval("3 * x **2")
```